# Count number of entries where Col1 has multiple entries with different data in Col2

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with two Columns, Col1 and Col2. I want to retrieve only the data when the Col1 has multiple entries with different data in Col2.

```
For example,                   I want to retain:
Col1       Col2                Col1       Col2
AB-123456  AP-321654           AB-123456  AP-321654
AB-123456  AP-321789           AB-123456  AP-321789          
AB-123456  AC-321456           AB-123456  AC-321456
AB-951357  AP-989898           AB-456851  AP-110211
AB-753159  AC-956854           AB-456851  AP-110279
AB-456851  AP-110211
AB-456851  AP-110279
```

I created through the Report feature a report that groups by Col1 and creates a subcount on the number of entries in Col2. Using the report, I seem to be having a problem with using the subtotal counter.  If the subtotal counter is > 1, I want to report, otherwise skip and go to the next Col1 data.

My next option was to write VBA code to read through the table and output the multiples to a new data, then I could run that data through the report to format, etc. To count the multiples and use criteria, I thought perhaps the DCount function would work. I have tried different variations, but to no avail.

Ex:

```
NUM_OF_MULTS = DCount("Col1", "TBL_Of_Col1_Col2", Current_Col2 = Prev_Col2)
  For Index1 = 1 to NUM_OF_MULTS ......
```

I tried different criteria, but it is either all the records or none.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your feedback. Your solution works1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should perform as you require:

```
select t1.* from YourTable t1
where exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 <> t2.col2)
```

Change both occurrences of `YourTable` to suit your table name.

For every record, this uses a correlated subquery to test whether another record exists in the dataset with the same `col1` value as the current record, but a different `col2` value, thus meeting your criteria.

The use of `select 1` is purely for optimisation: we don't care what data is returned by the subquery, only that it has records.

Comment: Thank you!  I tested both solutions and they work. Cannot tell you how much I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: @forpas I accept both solutions, would only let me select one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with SQL code you can use `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename as t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where Col1 = t.Col1 and Col2 <> t.Col2
)
```

and another option with the `IN` operator:

```
select * from tablename
where Col1 in (
  select Col1 
  from (select distinct Col1, Col2 from tablename)
  group by Col1
  having count(*) > 1
)
```